# EF 5: Compare two lists of entities and perform insert, update, delete where needed

Tags: .net, list, entity, compare

This is what i'm trying to do in Asp.net C#.

I'm importing products from a text-file that is synced every night. After syncing I create a list of product entities from the text-file and import them into a database. So far so good. But after the first sync is done, I have to compare the existing products from the database against the products from the text-file and the perform update, insert, delete against the database. Here is a piece of code, but now I'm stuck:

```
public class Product
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProductNumber { get; set; }

    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    //

    public virtual ICollection<StockItem> StockItems{ get; set; }

}

// Products from TXT have no Id-Property
List<Product> ProductsFromTXT = getProductsFromTXT();
List<Product> ProductsFromDB = getProductsFromDB();
```

Is it possible to compare the two list on changes of the entity Product and its properties? (Except the Id-property) And how do i get the new products and know what products to delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to define an equality comparer for the `Product` class. Assuming you're using the `ProductNumber` as the key:

```
public class ProductNumberEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
   public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
   {
      return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.ProductNumber.GetHashCode();
   }

   public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
   {
      if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
      if (x == null || y == null) return false;
      return x.ProductNumber == y.ProductNumber;
   }
}
```

You can then use that to find the items to add, edit and delete:

```
var comparer = new ProductNumberEqualityComparer();

var itemsToDelete = ProductsFromDB.Except(ProductsFromTXT, comparer).ToList();
foreach (Product item in itemsToDelete)
{
   // TODO: Delete the product
}

var itemsToUpdate = from dbProduct in ProductsFromDB
                    join txtProduct in ProductsFromTXT
                    on dbProduct.ProductNumber equals txtProduct.ProductNumber
                    select new
                    {
                       dbProduct,
                       txtProduct
                    };

foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
{
   // Update the product:
   item.dbProduct.Brand = item.txtProduct.Brand;
   item.dbProduct.Category = item.txtProduct.Category;
   item.dbProduct.Price = item.txtProduct.Price;

   // TODO: Update the stock items if required
}

var itemsToAdd = ProductsFromTXT.Except(ProductsFromDB, comparer).ToList();
foreach (Product item in itemsToAdd)
{
   // TODO: Add the product
}
```

Comment: That looks promising, and going to try this now. Thx Richard

Comment: Will This check all the properties of a class (entity)?

Comment: It's only comparing the `ProductNumber` property. If you want to use additional fields in the comparison, you'll need to add them to the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method of the equality comparer, and use an anonymous type in the `join` to find the items to update. Of course, if you're comparing all the fields, there'll be nothing to update! :)

Comment: thankx Richard, This was just what i'm looking for. Great anwser.